# How to solve power cut paypal issue?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing

Customer visit my e-commerce website. Orderd & Pay through paypal payment gateway. When he done payment due to internet issue or power cut issue amount deducted from his/her account. Then he/she is unable to return on my e-commerce website. So how can we manage this situation if amount is deducted from customer account & not returned back to our website.

Comment: keep trying and maybe you'll be the first to have an answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you get a notification when someone pays you money through paypal? Figure out a way to pass the order number to the paypal system.

Comment: No on return back we'r sending mail we r using paypal express checkout. Suppose we pass order number untill it return back to our website we will keep it's order status pending.

Comment: order status will be pending anyway until you receive the money, right? i'm not sure that i understand your problem.

Comment: yup. When it came back to our website & on basis of response we get from paypal we will proceed further like make entry in Database & send mail.